# I want to read space separated digit from text file and then store it into an array using struct

Tags: c

**My Text File:**

(same structure as pasted here---->2 digits separated by a space)

```
5 5
6 7
3 0
5 5
6 7
3 1
1 0
4 1
3 0
6 7
1 1
6 7
7 0
```

I have a struct, using which I have to store the values into an Array and then from there, I want to access the stored values.

**Source code that I'm using is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXPROGRAMSIZE 100
#define MAXDATASIZE 10
typedef struct Instruction{
    int opCode;
    int Address;
 } Instruction;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i=0;
    Instruction IM[MAXPROGRAMSIZE];
    fp = fopen("cgs.txt", "r"); //read file *use arg[i]
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Cannot open file!");
    else
    {

        printf("Assembling program...\n");
        while(fscanf(fp, "%d, %d", &IM[i].opCode, &IM[i].Address) != EOF)
        {
            i++;
        }
}
//this give me junk values
printf("\nm[i].opCode is %d\n", IM[1].Address);
return 0;
```

}

Please suggest me a solution, i tried different post from here to read space separated digits from text file and store values to array. Will be grateful. Thanks

Comment: sorry for adding c++ tag.

Comment: "No luck" is not a problem description. Also, you're using `fscanf` wrong: It can fail without returning `EOF`.

Comment: should i use the readline?

Comment: No, you should read the manual for `fscanf` and check what it's returning. And then you should investigate how and why it's failing.

Comment: yeah i should have a look on its documentation, sorry didn't do it before. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @melpomene One of the best answers I've seen here.

Comment: i tried to run program using fscanf and didn;t fail at EOF as you mentioned it can

Comment: `fscanf` does _not_ return `EOF`. It returns the _number_ of format matches, so you'd probably want (e.g.): `while(fscanf(fp, "%d, %d", &IM[i].opCode, &IM[i].Address) == 2)`

Comment: OT:  regarding; `int main(int argc,char *argv[])`  in the posted code, this causes the compiler to output two warning messages, one for each unused variable.  When the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, the use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Cannot open file!");`  1) this is not telling the user the root cause of the problem, so is not helpful.  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  A much better code sequence is: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  as this both outputs the error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: statement: `fp = fopen("cgs.txt", "r"); //read file *use arg[i]` claims that it is using `argv[1]`  however, the file name is hardcoded, not gotten from a command line parameter

Comment: regarding: `while(fscanf(fp, "%d, %d", &IM[i].opCode, &IM[i].Address) != EOF)`  What is the contents of the input file?

Comment: regarding `printf("\nm[i].opCode is %d\n", IM[1].Address);` the format parameter says `opCode`, but the data is `Address`

Comment: regarding printf('\n m[i].opCode') is for testing purpose

Comment: the content of the file is pasted above

Answer (score -1):

In fscanf, comma (,) is not correct

```
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d, %d", &IM[i].opCode, &IM[i].Address) != EOF)
```

Text file doesn't have it.